# Regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to obtain the two numbers on this expression:

```
s= "sfsdfafafadfafafa **34/23**"
```

I tried this:

```
import re 
re.search("\\*\\*[0-9][0-9]\\/[0-9][0-9]\\*\\*",s)
```

But Im getting None as an ouput, when at least I was expecting to get the expression.

Edit: Please take into consideration the ** as I would like to take them into account

**Edit:** The numbers can be between 1 and 6 digits

Comment: Use `regex = r"\*\*(\d+)\/(\d+)\*\*"` and extract first and second captured group to get the two digits.

Comment: Your example regular expression should match fine, but you haven’t showed the code you actually used (`re.search` takes two arguments, so it can’t return `None` here).

Comment: Thanks, I just edited. But even then it gives me none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
(\*\*\d+\/\d+\*\*)
```

`\d` is the same as `[0-9]`, it denotes all digits.

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/bHhrKj/3

### Apply to your code (You omitted the second argument):

```
import re 
re.search("(\*\*\d+\/\d+\*\*)", inputString)
```

Comment: Thanks, and that regex link is very useful

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
re.findall(r'\*\*(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\*\*', 'sfsdfafafadfafafa **34/23**')
```

will return an array containing a tuple `[('34', '23')]` that you can use to get the values from the string.